# camera does not have definition for field of view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fieldofview

unity console shows me the same error everytime "camera does not have definition for field of view"
i renamed field of view many time i wrote it with all of types but nothing happened
i tried following tutorials but i got the same error always
i tried to change the cinemachine FOV but i got also an error
plz help.....

this is my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations.Rigging;
using Cinemachine;
public class Movements : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cinemachine;

public Transform Cameratarget;
    public float turnSpeed = 15;
   
    public Camera MainCamera;
    public Animator anim;
    public Camera myCam;
    public Rig aimLayer;
    public float aimDuration = 0.3f;
    public float speed = 14f;
    public float elResitas  = -14f; 
   [SerializeField] Transform ZoomTarget;
    Cinemachine.CinemachineFreeLook elResitas2;
  
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
      elResitas2 = cinemachine.GetComponent<CinemachineFreeLook>();
      MainCamera = Camera.main;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
       myCam = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
   void FixedUpdate()
{
    
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX",0.17f);
      transform.Translate(new Vector3(0,0,speed)*Time.deltaTime);
      float yawCamera = MainCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, yawCamera, 0), turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
      
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX",-0.166f);
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0,0,elResitas)*Time.deltaTime);
        float yawCamera = MainCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, yawCamera, 0), turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        // Only reached if neither Z nor S is pressed!
        anim.SetFloat("MoveX", 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
         anim.SetFloat("MoveZ",0.208f);
      transform.Translate(new Vector3(speed,0,0)*Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("MoveZ",-0.2f);
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(elResitas,0,0)*Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        // Only reached if neither Q nor D is pressed!
        anim.SetFloat("MoveZ", 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse1))
    {
      elResitas2.m_LookAt = ZoomTarget.transform;
 


        speed = 6;
        elResitas = -6;
        aimLayer.weight += Time.deltaTime / aimDuration;
        float yawCamera = MainCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, yawCamera, 0), turnSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
     else
       {
     myCam.fieldofview = 30;
          elResitas2.m_LookAt = Cameratarget.transform;
           elResitas = -14;
           speed = 14;
           aimLayer.weight -= Time.deltaTime / aimDuration;
       }
     

}
}
```

Comment: its `fieldOfView`, case is relevant https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-fieldOfView.html

Comment: tried it but nothing happened 
same error always

Answer (score 0):

You are  trying to access property with  wrong  name. You are trying to access Field Of View Property Of Camera  as `fieldofview` , you need to replace `fieldofview`   with `fieldOfView` Everywhere you have used it.

Comment: tried it but nothing happened same error always